# Posts are being posted in two categories instead of 1

Tags: posts

When I create a post and assign the relevant category, the post ends up in the category I've assigned it to and another category. For example when I load a post to graphic design it automatically goes to blog as well. I want my graphic design and my blog to be separate. I've done some research but I don't know what to do.

Comment: are you using a specific theme or a default WordPress theme? This is important because a custom theme could be the reason. It may not be set up to pull posts by category

Comment: is one of the categories a child category of the other? the default category archive page will usually include the posts of child categories.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the post shows up on the blog index and in the category index then that is how it is supposed to work.

Based on your statement that you "want [your] graphic design and [your] blog to be separate" then [create a custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) for your graphic design. Copy the ["Books" post type from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Example), place it in a plugin file, and edit the first parameter of `register_post_type` and the `$labels` values.

You will get a new menu similar to "Posts" and "Pages" for your "Graphic Design" and it will have its own archive page. It will be completely separate from your blog posts.